# Automatic water pump Trigger System - I need my code FIXED

Tags: arduino-nano, atmega328, code-review, code-optimization, prototype

```
int out = LED_BUILTIN;
int strt = 3;
int stp = 9;
void setup() {
  pinMode(out,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(strt,INPUT);
  pinMode(stp,INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  while(true) {  
    if(digitalRead(strt) == LOW) {
      digitalWrite(out,HIGH);
      delay(1000);
    }
    if(digitalRead(stp) == HIGH) {
      digitalWrite(out, LOW);
      delay(1000);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm a beginner so I believe someone would help me out. Actually the mechanism I'm using for turning the state of Pin 3 & 9 is through 3 wires connected to the **Pins D3,D9 & 5V** in the nano board. Where 5 V is immersed in water and Pin 3 does not touch water Nano's *Built in LED* is turned on and if the water reaches Pin 9 (while the Pin 3 wire is still submerged under water) the LED goes Off.

In the above code, the Built in LED turns High just fine if Input Pin 3 Reads Low. Although as soon as Pin 3 goes High the LED turns Low and does not wait for Reading input pin 9 which is when the LED should actually turn Off.

In the first **IF** Clause (For Reading **Pin 3(strt) to LOW**) I want that part of the code to only set the OUTPUT pin ***LED_BUILTIN*** to be set to **HIGH** & not revert back to **LOW** if **pin 3** is turned to **HIGH**. But only if the INPUT **pin 9** in the second **IF** Clause reads **HIGH** then only should the OUTPUT Pin ***LED_BUILTIN*** be set to **LOW**.

Thank You for the helping hand.

This is the Link for the Code that I used(I Modified the code to have two input Wires) : https://www.instructables.com/Water-Level-Alarm-Using-Arduino/

Comment: `as soon as Pin 3 goes High the LED turns Low ` - that makes no sense. The only way the LED can go LOW is if pin 9 reads high.

Comment: That is right . That's what was supposed to happen. But as I said earlier when the wire connected to Pin 3 touches the water (ie Pin 3 Goes High) LED goes LOW. But I want nothing to happen if Pin 3 goes High. Only if Pin 3 goes Low should the LED turn on. I hope I'm clear. Please help me!

Comment: the `while(true){` is redundant .... loop() already does that

Comment: change your code so that the led is controled by pin 3 only ... verify that the harware responds as expected by repeatedy dipping pin 3 wire in water (shorten the delay for this)